# DataGrid does not execute double click event on editable cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

**Goal**

The goal is to execute a command on a double click on selected row.

**Problem**

When I double click a cell, it goes into edit mode and does not execute the command.

[image]

If I double click the empty cell on the right of column `Data` - it executes the command.

Also, if I set `IsReadOnly` to `true`, it works.. it just doesn't work with editable cells.

**Question**

Why does the double click event not work with editable cells?

**Code to reproduce the problem**

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SampleModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Command}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

**Model**

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class SampleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> SampleModels { get; set; }

    private SampleModel _selectedItem;

    public SampleModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        if(SampleModels == null)
        {
            SampleModels = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>();
        }
        SampleModels.Clear();

        SampleModels.Add(new SampleModel { Id = 1, Data = "Item 1" });
        SampleModels.Add(new SampleModel { Id = 2, Data = "Item 2" });
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; }
    private void TestMethod()
    {
        var a = SelectedItem;
    }


    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
        Command = new RelayCommand(param => TestMethod());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the double click event not work with editable cells?

Because the `DataGrid` control handles the double-click by entering the edit mode of the cell. How else would you be able to edit the cell?

You could handle the double-click in the cells using an attached behaviour:

```
public static class DoubleClickBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(UIElement element) =>
        (ICommand)element.GetValue(CommandProperty);

    public static void SetCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value) =>
        element.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(DoubleClickBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnChanged));

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = (UIElement)d;
        if (e.NewValue is ICommand command)
        {
            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
        else
        {
            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
    }

    private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
            ICommand command = GetCommand(element);
            if (command != null)
                command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage**:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SampleModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Command}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="local:DoubleClickBehavior.Command"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.Command,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```